# SQL Server Transactional Replication - what is sp_MSreleasesnapshotdeliverysessionlock?

Tags: sql-server

Occasionally when creating and finishing a snapshot to re-sync data, some of the subscribers seem to hang about for several hours afterwards before they start to take the snapshot. There's no blocking that I can see on the distributor. When I check on the subscriber for sessions against the subscription database, they are running: sp_MSreleasesnapshotdeliverysessionlock

This sometimes happens on a number of SQL Server versions, but all patched to recent CUs. What is this process? And what is likely to be going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It's important to understand where is the bottleneck...

Are the BCP-files for the snapshot actually getting created?
Are you using PULL or PUSH subscriptions?
Remote or Local DIST?
Can you setup a Profiler Trace or XE Session on each component...PUB, DIST and SUB and trace activity...plus maybe look at wait-stats and what SQL is waiting for?
Turn on Verbose-logging for LogReader-Agent and Distribution-Agent as well.
Query the History Replication Sys-Table to get additional information too...
sp_helptext on sp_MSreleasesnapshotdeliverysessionlock - what is in it?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helpful or not, but that sp is a built in sproc within the Master database you can look at the code within it.

The tag line is:

This procedure is used by the distribution/merge agent to release the application lock acquired through sp_MSacquiresnapshotdeliverysessionlock.

Looking at the second 'aquire' stored procedure that creates a snapshot delivery progress table, wondering if this process is taking some time?